# Apache Nifi Oracle JDBC configuration

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, apache-nifi, ojdbc, mongo-jdbc-driver

I tried to connect to an Oracle server using Apache Nifi's jdbc oracle driver, but I need the precise fields to setup the processor. Help me to sort out this issue :

[image]

Comment: driver class name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver. Then the location should point to your ojdbc8.jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Put `ojdbc6.jar` or `ojdbc8.jar` inside `lib` directory of NiFi and add `DBCPConnectionPool` Controller Service properties as below.

If you don't have access to `lib` then use a custom location to keep JDBC jar, just make sure that NiFi has permissions to access this location.

[image]

Comment: No need to obscure the ip, host name, DB user etc., you can rather use generic naming styles everybody can encounter everywhere...